# How can I change my code to show "" and not '' in a echo?

Tags: php, html, quotes, double-quotes

How can I change this code:

```
echo "<button onclick='document.location='TEST1.php?auteurnr=$row[0]''> $row[voornaam] $row[achternaam]</button>";
```

Into showing this:

```
<button onclick="document.location='test1.php?auteurnr=61'">
```

And not this:

```
<button onclick='document.location='TEST1.php?auteurnr=61''>
```

Comment: escape the double quotes `\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean character escaping?

```
echo "<button onclick=\"document.location='TEST1.php?auteurnr=$row[0]'\"> $row[voornaam] $row[achternaam]</button>";
```

Comment: Thnx you are the best.